# Save Image on sdcard, also show progress in notification

Tags: android, android-intent, imagedownload

I have a list of images, they are on a server and I want to download the image and save it on my sdcard. Also I need to show the progress in the notification area at the top. I need the most simple way to do it. The image will be downloaded in background so I know I have to use asyncTask but I want to use handlers if it is possible. Also if I can download the image by calling the default gallery that will be really good. And is there any way to implement the long press functionality on an image when it is displayed in the android browser I would recommend it. I am open to suggestions please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: All your questions are already answered on SO.
Just search and you will find.

Comment: Can you please show me the links ? Thanks

Comment: Just google ... I googled your exact question... Click: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+save+image+on+sd+card&oq=android+save+image+on+sd+card if you are not able to google ... 

There are plenty of links form SO itself on the first page...

Comment: You got me wrong then. I can google code snippets. I need a suggestion.